# How can i change single Listview's item ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatemplate, listviewitem

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:key="AwesomeDataTemplate" >
  (Awesome stuff here...)
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:key="GodLikeDataTemplate" >
  (Something better here...)
</DataTemplate>
```

I have a `Listview` with some `ListViewItem`s in it. The `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate` is **AwesomeDataTemplate** by default. When i hover to a `ListViewItem`, is it possible to change the hovered `ListViewItem`'s item template to **GodLikeDataTemplate**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can do something like that. Use trigger and change DataTemplate of ContentTemplate property.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewSample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Haha my code is almost identic with yours. I used `Template` instead of `ContentTemplate` and thats why it always return error :v Btw, Thx for helping!